# how to send gridview in mail using asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, email

I am new to asp.net. Now manager asked me to write a function to send grid view in mail using asp.net. I don't no anything ..please give a step by step tutorial link...

```
 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }
```

Comment: please refer this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19051754/sending-aspx-page-with-gridviews-as-email/19052128#19052128

Comment: I got the solution pradeep..!! Tanks for your intrest :) Try this link  http://aj-learning.com/blog/send-gridview-email-asp-net/

Answer (score 1):

USe this [Code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1900128/c-sharp-sending-gridviews-datatables-via-email):

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Label1.Text = getHTML(GridView1);
    }

    private string getHTML(GridView gv) 
    { 
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(); 
        StringWriter textwriter = new StringWriter(sb); 
        HtmlTextWriter htmlwriter = new HtmlTextWriter(textwriter); 
        gv.RenderControl(htmlwriter); 
        htmlwriter.Flush(); 
        textwriter.Flush(); 
        htmlwriter.Dispose(); 
        textwriter.Dispose(); 
        return sb.ToString(); 
    }
```

For send mail:

```
 SmtpClient smtpClient = new SmtpClient("mail.MyWebsiteDomainName.com", 25);

    smtpClient.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("info@MyWebsiteDomainName.com", "myIDPassword");
                smtpClient.UseDefaultCredentials = true;
                smtpClient.DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network;
                smtpClient.EnableSsl = true;
                MailMessage mail = new MailMessage();


                //Setting From , To and CC
                mail.From = new MailAddress("info@MyWebsiteDomainName", "MyWeb Site");
                mail.To.Add(new MailAddress("info@MyWebsiteDomainName"));
                mail.CC.Add(new MailAddress("MyEmailID@gmail.com"));


    smtpClient.Send(mail);
```